# what's the error here in fetching in post method using react

Tags: reactjs, fetch, http-post, backend

React Code which i used in frontend
the data from frontend not going to backend
the backend perfectly works as i tested it using postman
someone help to solve

idk whats the error the data from front end not going to backend ig

```
at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:4164:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:4213:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4277:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError (react-dom.development.js:4291:1)
    at executeDispatch (react-dom.development.js:9041:1)
    at processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder (react-dom.development.js:9073:1)
    at processDispatchQueue (react-dom.development.js:9086:1)
    at dispatchEventsForPlugins (react-dom.development.js:9097:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:9288:1
```

this is whats shown

can anyone help me please

Answer (score 0):

> https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-almeida-vlh125?file=/src/App.js

I have replicated the Frontend code and put it into useEffect with hardcoding the body and it is working

and also it is reflected on your backend server.

The issue might be related to your state.

Comment: Even hardcoding didn't work... i already tried

Comment: I will need to see more of your code to know what the actual problem you are facing you can make a codesandbox for your frontend code just like how i have share above